# Why is *x=[1,2,3,4] invalid when *x,y=[1,2,3,4] is legal?

Tags: python

I'm wondering why the following code is invalid, I'm using python3

```
*x =[1,2,3,4]
```

however if i just add one more variable

```
*x, y =[1,2,3,4]
```

the code will be valid, could anyone explain ?
thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: [Are you sure about that?](http://ideone.com/vDXz7y)

Comment: @user2357112: No. I interpreted the question the other way around, my bad.

Comment: what do you expect `*x = [1,2,3,4]` to do?

Comment: In terms of "why" -- what utility would this syntax have? If it doesn't have utility, that's an argument not to define it -- undefined syntax is space where extensions can be introduced later; populating this space unnecessarily makes a language spec difficult to extend.

Answer (score 8):

A starred assignment target must be part of an unpacking. It represents "take the items not consumed by the rest of this unpacking and assign a list of those items to this assignment target".

When you do

```
*x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`*x` is not part of an unpacking, so this is invalid. If you make it the only element of an unpacking:

```
*x, = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# or
[*x] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then it's valid.

The [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) that introduced the syntax mentions this restriction:

> It is also an error to use the starred expression as a lone assignment
>   target, as in
>
> ```
> *a = range(5)
> ```
>
> This, however, is valid syntax:
>
> ```
> *a, = range(5)
> ```

While they could have defined `*x = thing` to mean the same as `[*x] = thing`, it would be a special case with no real benefit.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), emphasis mine:

> Specification
>
> A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain at most one expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a "starred" expression

...

> **It is also an error to use the starred expression as a lone assignment target, as in**

```
*a = range(5)
```

to perform the above, you'll have to do `a = list(range(5))` (you have to convert to list to simulate unpacking, or following the resulting error message `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`, do `[*a] = range(5)`

Comment: I don't see why you bolded the part about "the other expressions in the list are called "mandatory"". It's not actually mandatory to have other expressions in the unpacking; the "mandatory" means that it's mandatory to provide values to unpack into any unstarred assignment targets. You can have an unpacking that doesn't contain other assignment targets, like `[*x] = [1, 2, 3, 4]` or `*x, = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 3):

The starred expression needs to be inside of a tuple or list, since the purpose of it is to take all values not grabbed by the other variables for assignment. When you do

```
*x, y = [1,2,3,4]
```

the x & y pair are implicitly in a tuple, so it works.

Note that if you want to have x alone be the target, you can just put it in a list for assignment:

```
[*x] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> *x = [1, 3, 4]
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple
```

Just like it said, **starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple.**